# Safe way to truncate SQL Server Error Log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, disk-space, errors, truncate

We are running out of space. What is the safe way to clear the error log?

[image: What is the safe way to clear this?]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can cycle the error log by calling `sp_cycle_errorlog` and then that will close the current error log and cycle the log extensions.  Basically, it'll create a new error log file that SQL Server will be hitting.  Then the archived error log(s) can be treated accordingly (delete/move with caution).  This will not technically "truncate" the log, it'll just roll it over and you can handle the old logs as you so please, like any other file system file.

When you do this, you should see a new log file with an entry that resembles the following:

> The error log has been reinitialized. See the previous log for older entries.

[BOL reference on `sp_cycle_errorlog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182512%28v=sql.105%29)

Comment: It's worth noting that sp_cycle_errorlog only recycles ONE log file. But because there are 7 files, if you really want to purge them and save space (as I did) you will need to run the command several times (7 times to be exact). And each time you run it one of these files will be shrunk:
ErrorLog
ErrorLog.1
ErrorLog.2
ErrorLog.3
ErrorLog.4
ErrorLog.5
ErrorLog.6