# SQL Server Errorlog file not releasing space when recycled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, disk-space

I had a series of SQL Server errorlog (1 to 6) files taking up 39GB.  I needed the space for database growth.  Being a belt and braces sort of guy, I zipped them (or moved them to compressed folder) first.  This reduced the 39GB to 1GB.  I therefore expected to see my disk free space increase by 38GB.  But no!  Stayed exactly the same.

I tried restoring them back, but this didn't complete as there was only the original 10GB free and not enough space for an extra 38GB.  I recycled the logs 6 times using sp_cycle_errorlog in case SQL had somehow kept hold of them.  This reduced the size to a handful of KB as expected, but still made no difference to the disk free space.

Never seen anything like this before.  Anyone any ideas?

SQL 2012, Windows 2012, hosted on VMWare.

Comment: You might try installing something like [TreeSize Professional](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/) to help you find what is consuming the space. I have seen cases where it was anti-virus or patches that were the source of my space problems.

Comment: [Safe way to truncate SQL Server Error Log](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/31298/15356)

Comment: How do you have 40 GB of error data on 6 files? Do you not cycle the error log often or has something gone completely haywire on your server?

Comment: @SQL_Underworld - no, we do not cycle the logs regularly, and we had a transaction log reaching its maximum extents issue...